# How to optimize or make this dynamic (html javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm still new in html javascript. I want to ask can i use for loop to optimize or make this dynamic

```
 var port = [];         
 port[0]=$('#slcPort_0').val();
 port[1]=$('#slcPort_1').val();
 port[2]=$('#slcPort_2').val();
 port[3]=$('#slcPort_3').val();
 port[4]=$('#slcPort_4').val();
```

i used this code in function to retrieve data from html form

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can do the following:

```
var port = Array();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  port[i] = $("#slcPort_"+i).val();
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yiyaruweja/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
// selects all the elements whose 'id' starts-with "slcPort_":
var port = $('[id^=slcPort_]').map(function(){
              // returns the value from those elements:
              return this.value;
          // converts to an array:
          }).get();
```

This isn't guaranteed to be in numerical order, though it will be in order of the appearance of those elements in the DOM.

References:

- [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^=value]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to give all those elements a class, like `slcPort`. Then something like

```
var port = [];
$.each($('.slcPort'), function(index,value) {
    port[index] = $(value).val();
});
```

Much prettier. Plus all those elements are related anyways, so just class em up.

[$.each documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)